# Viewer started to display odd quality

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like to copy the viewer settings similar to which that are used in the translated files (View results) coming from `models.autodesk.io`

It seems to me that there has been a recent change in the API, as my settings no longer displays the way it used to. Now it shows a very grainy almost graphite like result:

[image]

These are my settings:

```
viewer.disableHighlight(true);                          viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, onSelectionChanged);
viewer.setLightPreset(2);
viewer.setEnvMapBackground(false);
viewer.setQualityLevel(true, true);
viewer.setGroundShadow(false);
viewer.setGroundReflection(false);
viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true);
viewer.setDisplayEdges(false);
viewer.setOptimizeNavigation(true);
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations.
Problem firt occours when I add the URN to my app. Showing it from the models.autodesk.io looks great and crisp. I would like to copy those settings if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your app is using the same Viewer version as models.autodesk.io, which currently is `v3.3` and [version your code](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/09/forge-viewer-always-use-versioning-in-production-code.html).

If you look at [the source for of it](http://view-source:https://models.autodesk.io/view.html), you'll there is not custom visual effect, just the default.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out that wasn't the problem. The problem was the MAX file. It seems to me like there's been some changes to how the translation process of MAX files very recently. They no longer access the MESH but the Material name for the objects, and the camera no longer needs a free camera in Front view, and the results is very grainy. Maybe the 3ds Max workflow is under construction.